# How to disable iOS UIKit app landscape view on M1 Mac?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, apple-m1

I am running an iOS-only **UIKit app** with device orientation "Portrait" selected only and **no iPad support**. However, after the app launch, the view can still be “resized" to the landscape orientation.

Is there a way to disable this behavior on an M1 Mac?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe you could set the minimum and maximum window size so that it does not change its size to an unwanted size: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419206-minsize

Comment: It is an iOS app, not a macOS app.

Comment: How does your app handle being resized for split view on an iPad? The whole idea of portrait vs. landscape is almost meaningless these days; all apps should be able to adapt to different view sizes because they can't assume that they'll get the whole screen.

Comment: @Caleb the app has no iPad support.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. A UIKit app that is not an iPad app but is something that works on an M1 Mac? I have code (and yes, it only works in code) that determines - through UIKit - is you are in portrait or landscape and adjusts the layout accordingly. But from your description (and lack of code) I don't think it'll help. And as an FYI? Last I knew *all* iOS (or UIKit) apps that work for an iPhone *do* run on iPad.